# how can i use this file in docker?

Tags: docker

i want to use crawlab dashboard with my crawler code.
crawlab is crawl dashboard. the link is https://github.com/crawlab-team/crawlab

i want to install(?) chromedriver in docker(?).

this is file tree

[image]

how can i use 'install-chromedriver.sh' in this?

Comment: First, what do you mean by using `install-chromedriver.sh`? Do you mean in your own code? Second, what is your crawler code? You have not provided enough information for us to understand how your crawler code functions. That script might be custom to `crawlab`

Comment: @astrochun oh! thx giving me your time to say that. i could solve that issue ! thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install Chrome Driver for each node simply through the Crawlab web page.

Nodes -> Installation -> Web Driver -> Chrome Driver

[image: Crawlab snapshot]